# Origin of "Ampel"

Tags: etymology

What is the origin and original meaning of the word "Ampel"?

Comment: Im Wiktionary steht was zur Herkunft des Wortes. Daher ist die Frage hier eher unpassend, da trivial beantwortbar. Es sei denn natürlich, du hast dir den Eintrag dort durchgelesen und weiterführende Fragen dazu. Dann bist du hier goldrichtig.

Comment: @RolandIllig: Ein guter Artikel in Wikipedia, oder Wiktionary allein sollte nicht als Grund gelten, eine Frage als *zu einfach*, also *off topic* zu schließen. Ich gebe aber zu, dass es für die Frage hier eindeutig besser wäre, wenn uns ein wenig mehr Hintergrund oder eigene Rechercheergebnisse mitgeteilt worden wären. Vielleicht hat die Frage auch deshalb kein Upvote erhalten.

Comment: VtR reviewers: this question is about etymology, which is ontopic!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Wie im [zitierten](https://german.stackexchange.com/a/48257/23) Brockhaus richtig vermerkt stammt unsere *[Ampel](https://dwds.de/wb/Ampel)* vom lateinischen *[ampulla](https://www.frag-caesar.de/lateinwoerterbuch/Ampulla-uebersetzung-1.html)* ab, dort in der Bedeutung eines kleinen Gefäßes, oder einer Salbenflasche.

Erst ab dem Mittelalter kommt bei uns die Bedeutung einer *Lampe* hinzu (die im Latein *lucerna*, *cymbium* oder *lumen* hieß), wohl wegen der Verwendung von Öllampengefäßen, zunächst in Kirchen, dann auch in den Behausungen.

[image]
<sup>Kirchenampel. Quelle: [Wikmedia](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/9/92/Ampel.Ewiges.Licht.jpg/450px-Ampel.Ewiges.Licht.jpg)</sup>

In dieser Bedeutung, nämlich einer Lichtquelle kam erst in der Neuzeit auch die über dem Verkehr hängende umgangssprachliche Verkers**ampel** hinzu (die eigentlich *Lichtzeichenanlage* heißt). Die ursprüngliche Bedeutung eines Gefäßes ist uns in der Blumen**ampel** erhalten geblieben.

Erst in den letzten Jahren wird unter *Ampel* auch die Farbkombination rot-gelb-grün verstanden ([Ampelkoalition](https://dwds.de/wb/Ampelkoalition), [Ampelkarte](https://dwds.de/wb/Ampelkarte)).

Answer (score 7):

Der Brockhaus <sup>1</sup> sagt uns zur Frage, wo das Wort *Ampel* herkommt:

> ampulla - Lat. "Fläschchen"

Die Römer und andere Bewohner der Spätantike nutzten kleine Schnabelkännchen aus Ton oder Bronze mit Öl und einem Docht zur Beleuchtung ihrer Wohnungen.

---

<sup>1)</sup> Hier Auflage 19, 1. Band, S. 508.